# Deleting the content of multiple csv file with python

Tags: python, csv

I am using the following code to delete the content of a single csv file:

```
filename = "output.csv"
# opening the file with w+ mode truncates the file
f = open(filename, "w+")
f.close()
```

Is there a way to this at the same time to multiple csv files which are in the same folder? Basically I want to keep the filenames and only to delete their content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#glob.glob) package in the standard library to get a list of files by extension in a directory:

```
import glob

for csv_file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    open(csv_file, "w+").close()
```

Comment: Works great. Thaks.